# After changing file permissions, 403 error forbidden to Admin-Categories

Tags: magento-1.7, error, magento-community, server-setup, file-permissions

In Magento 1.7, I just tried accessing `Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories`, and I got a `403` Forbidden error (`You don't have permission to accesson -url- on this server.`).

Before that, I modified the file and folder permissions, and I wonder if I did something wrong when doing so and that's why now I can't access it.

Which are the appropriate file and folder permissons? Any ideas why I cannot access the Categories section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed the mod security rule, 
Please check below url for 403 error :

https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/403-Forbidden-on-when-trying-to-Manage-Categories/m-p/16952#M810

Comment: Thank you. I already saw this thread. Should I contact my host provider? Are they responsible for any possible changes in mod_security? And if so, should I ask them to revert the changes or what should I ask?

Comment: Yes , you can contact with your host provider.

Comment: Could you please tell me which are the appropriate folders/files permissions ?

Comment: Contacting the hosting provider did the work. Thank you.